# Dangling meta character

Tags: java, regex

I keep getting an error about dangling meta character when I use '+', '*', '(', and ')'.

I've already tried escaping those characters in the regex but I still get the error. This is what I have:

```
"[-\\+\\*/%\\(\\)]"
```

**Update:**

test:

```
String input = "+";

String vals = new WNScanner(input).getNextToken();    //**********
System.out.println("token: " + vals);
System.out.println(vals.matches("[-+*/%()]"));
```

from another class:

```
    ...

    String expression = input;
    ...

public String getNextToken() {

    String[] token = {""};

    if (expression.length() == 0)
        return "";

    token = expression.split("\\s");
    recentToken = token[0];
    expression = expression.replaceFirst(token[0], "");     //*************
    expression = expression.trim();

    return token[0];


}
```

***** there are exceptions on these lines.

Comment: None of those require backslash escaping within "[]"s (however, "-" must be the first character inside the "[]"s).

Comment: @ShadowCreeper oh. but I still get the error if I don't include the backslashes. any idea?

Comment: Post your attempt (code) with error message in the question (you can pare it down to a simple class or a single function).

Comment: @ShadowCreeper I updated my post. Hope it's clear

Comment: What is input? What is expression? why doesn't getNextToken return something?

Comment: Sorry. I kind of omitted some things because it was too long. getNextToken returns token[0]. I just input something like '-' or '+'.  Also, expression = input

Comment: Do you want to match the _whole input_ with your regex, or only find whether the regex matches anywhere in the input?

Comment: @fge match the whole input

Comment: Well, actually, the problem is more simple than that; see my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I don't know what you want to achieve there... Especially at this line:

```
expression = expression.replaceFirst(token[0], "");
```

If your input string is `"+"`, then *your whole regex* is `+`. And that is not legal.

You need to quote the input string in order to use it in any regex-related operation, and that includes `String`'s `.replaceFirst()` and `.replaceAll()` (but *not* `.replace()`...).

Therefore, do:

```
final String re = Pattern.quote(token[0]);
expression = expression.replaceFirst(re, "");
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That solved the issue. But can you please explain what Pattern is?

Comment: `Pattern` is the JDK's basic class for regex processing. You create a regex object by calling the static factory method `Pattern.compile()`. Another static method of this class is the method used here, `.quote()`, which, given a `String` as an input, will quote all metacharacters in it so that a regex created from that string is automatically valid. [Full javadoc for `Pattern` here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Note: don't forget to accept the answer ;)